# How to Pass index in the onChange of autocomplete - React material UI

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, onchange, setstate

How can we pass index in the onChange method of autocomplete. I am able to set the state of ItemNumber, if I hardcode index as zero. But have trouble setting the index as such. Can anyone guide me.

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

export class Item extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        currentItem: [{
            itemNumber: [],
        }],

    };
}
```

working code for setting the state of 'itemNumber'.
But have trouble passing index (instead of currentItem[0], index should be passed. Like currentItem[i]).

```
onChangeHandleInput  = (event, value) => {            
    let currentItem= [...this.state.currentItem];        
    currentItem[0].itemNumber= value;  
    this.setState({ currentItem});
}


    render() {
        const currentItem= Object.values(this.state.currentItem);

        return (
            <div>
                    {currentItem.map((element, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="box">
                                                          
                            <Autocomplete
                            id="itemNumber"
                            value={element.itemNumber}
                            options={this.state.Data}
                            getOptionLabel={option => option}
                            onChange={this.onChangehandleInput}
                            //onChange={() => this.onChangeCaptureAutComItemNo(index)}
                            renderInput={params => (
                                <TextField {...params} fullWidth />
                            )}
                            />

                       </div>
                    );
           </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Change your onChangeHandleInput function to take a third index parameter. Then use the commented onChange with the only difference of changing the empty function “()” to this: “(event, value)” and pass these values together with index to onChangeHandleInput

Comment: Maybe change your fn to accept these three params, then... `onChange={(event, value) => this.onchangeHandleInput(event, value, index)}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For situations like this I prefer to curry the extraneous parameters. Here is the callback that takes the index as an argument and returns a callback function to later take the `onChange` event and value. The `index` is closed over in callback scope.

```
onChangeHandleInput = index => (event, value) => {            
  const currentAsset = [...this.state.currentAsset];        
  currentAsset[index].serienr = value;  
  this.setState({ currentAsset });
}
```

Usage:

```
{currentAsset.map((element, index) => {
  return (
    <div className="box">                             
      <Autocomplete
        id="itemNumber"
        value={element.itemNumber}
        options={this.state.Data}
        getOptionLabel={option => option}
        onChange={this.onChangehandleInput(index)}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField {...params} fullWidth />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
})}
```

If you prefer to keep the callback function signature simple you can update it to take the 3 arguments and proxy the change event object and value to the handler.

```
onChangeHandleInput = (event, value, index) => {            
  const currentAsset = [...this.state.currentAsset];        
  currentAsset[index].serienr = value;  
  this.setState({ currentAsset });
}
```

Usage:

```
{currentAsset.map((element, index) => {
  return (
    <div className="box">                             
      <Autocomplete
        id="itemNumber"
        value={element.itemNumber}
        options={this.state.Data}
        getOptionLabel={option => option}
        onChange={(e, val) => this.onChangehandleInput(e, val, index)}
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField {...params} fullWidth />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to keep the callback function signature simple you can update it to take the 3 arguments and proxy the change event object and value to the handler.